# How are fluid simulations handled in Computer Graphics?

Tags: animation, pbr, simulation, fluid-sim

How are fluid simulations handled in Computer Graphics? For a novice, there are hardly any novice friendly tutorials explaining how particles or fluids can be simulated.

Things like smoke, crown splashes and fog are they animated by artists as opposed to physically based simulations?

If there are any worthwhile resources that you could recommend please do! :)

Comment: Yes there is a good tutorial called [12 steps to CFD](http://lorenabarba.com/blog/cfd-python-12-steps-to-navier-stokes/).

Comment: This seems like a really broad question. (And I'm not sure if recommendations are allowed on this stack exchange. They're usually frowned upon.) Can you narrow down what you're having trouble understanding with fluid sims?

Comment: See Bridson and Müller-Fischer's notes from their SIGGRAPH 2007 course, *[Fluid Simulation for Computer Animation](http://www.cs.ubc.ca/~rbridson/fluidsimulation/)*. You should also consider picking up [Bridson's book](https://www.crcpress.com/Fluid-Simulation-for-Computer-Graphics-Second-Edition/Bridson/9781482232837) which has more detail.